# When checking ssh to github connection with ssh -T git@github.com does git@github.com refer to github account email or do we type the command as is?

Tags: github, ssh

I typed as is:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

But I get:

```
Received disconnect from github ip address ports: Bye Bye
Disconnected from ips and ports.
```

I have tried reinstalling visual studio multiple times.

Comment: You enter the command as-is, don't replace it with your own email or account name. See: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Comment: As is. Consider this: How would `ssh` know to connect to github.com if you didn't write github.com in the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the literal command to run. You should receive an appropriate message if authentication is successful. For example (using an explicit ssh key):

```
ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/github git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/home/match/.ssh/github': 

Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. i added the fingerprint.